# Mysql process goes over 3500% of CPU usage and Qcache_lowmem_prunes too high

Tags: mysql, cpu-usage

I am experiencing problems with mysql CPU usage after a sharp increase in online users last night. The average server load was 150 (1 min) and the mysql CPU usage in top was 3500-4000%. The show processlist; result was 250 queries. Here is some settings and statuses:

```
max_connections=400
query_cache_type=1
join_buffer_size=4096
query_cache_size=5M
query_cache_limit=1048576
query_cache_min_res_unit=4096
```

Here is the execution of the

```
show status like '%qcach%';
```

3 times in 30 seconds

```
+-------------------------+------------+
| Variable_name           | Value      |
+-------------------------+------------+
| Qcache_free_blocks      | 597        |
| Qcache_free_memory      | 1658184    |
| Qcache_hits             | 1813237610 |
| Qcache_inserts          | 456473072  |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes    | 433310255  |
| Qcache_not_cached       | 105476947  |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache | 1564       |
| Qcache_total_blocks     | 4027       |
+-------------------------+------------+
+-------------------------+------------+
| Variable_name           | Value      |
+-------------------------+------------+
| Qcache_free_blocks      | 429        |
| Qcache_free_memory      | 1422288    |
| Qcache_hits             | 1813245095 |
| Qcache_inserts          | 456475419  |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes    | 433312602  |
| Qcache_not_cached       | 105477523  |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache | 1553       |
| Qcache_total_blocks     | 3896       |
+-------------------------+------------+
+-------------------------+------------+
| Variable_name           | Value      |
+-------------------------+------------+
| Qcache_free_blocks      | 481        |
| Qcache_free_memory      | 1546088    |
| Qcache_hits             | 1813254695 |
| Qcache_inserts          | 456477824  |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes    | 433314721  |
| Qcache_not_cached       | 105478263  |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache | 1699       |
| Qcache_total_blocks     | 4146       |
+-------------------------+------------+
```

Server configuration:

```
2 x Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v4 @ 2.20GHz.
64GB RAM
Mysql running on SSDs.
```

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the query_cache_size to 128M.
The mysql procces uses much less CPU than before.

2 minutes after flushing status the result:

```
| Qcache_free_blocks      | 15777    |
| Qcache_free_memory      | 66772864 |
| Qcache_hits             | 74013    |
| Qcache_inserts          | 5293     |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes    | 0        |
| Qcache_not_cached       | 5125     |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache | 37880    |
| Qcache_total_blocks     | 92907
```

However, after 5-10 minutes Qcache_lowmem_prunes starts increasing again (maybe slower than before, but still increasing with 50-100 points per second).

I dont think that the problem is query_cache_size anymore.

7 minutes after the flush:

```
| Qcache_free_blocks      | 14825    |
| Qcache_free_memory      | 54665504 |
| Qcache_hits             | 534784   |
| Qcache_inserts          | 44569    |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes    | 6194     |
| Qcache_not_cached       | 34718    |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache | 49212    |
| Qcache_total_blocks     | 114243   |
+-------------------------+----------+

AVG Query Size = 1616
Frag Indicator = 12.98%
Utilisation = 59.27%
Removal Ratio = 13.9%
Hit Rate = 87.09%
```

After that I have changed query_cache_min_res_unit to 2048.
10 minutes after flush status:

```
| Qcache_free_blocks      | 21987    |
| Qcache_free_memory      | 38858856 |
| Qcache_hits             | 255849   |
| Qcache_inserts          | 20100    |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes    | 15638    |
| Qcache_not_cached       | 16691    |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache | 64573    |
| Qcache_total_blocks     | 152132   |

AVG Query Size = 1477
Frag Indicator = 14.45%
Utilisation = 71%
Removal Ratio = 79%
Hit Rate = 87%
```

Comment: Please post in question (or pastebin.com) current complete my.cnf/ini and php.ini (if used)
Text results of: 
A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; 
B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
C) complete current text of error log
D) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop   OR  top for most active apps
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -x       for a linux/unix when BUSY for IOPS of hardware  extended status.
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device
free -m  for a linux/unix free memory report
MySQLTuner.com  entire report.

Answer (score 1):

Wilson Hauck thank you for your reply.
I have changed only query_cache_min_res_unit to 512 as you wrote.
10 hours after FLUSH STATUS:

```
| Qcache_free_blocks      | 65446    |
| Qcache_free_memory      | 53083696 |
| Qcache_hits             | 39641904 |
| Qcache_inserts          | 2559829  |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes    | 240861   |
| Qcache_not_cached       | 2564542  |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache | 155462   |
| Qcache_total_blocks     | 385780   |

AVG Query Size = 1385
Frag Indicator = 16.96%
Utilisation = 80%
Removal Ratio = 9.4%
Hit Rate = 88.56%
```

As you can see, Removal Ratio is now under 10%. I think this is good. Do I really need to change the other variables?

Comment: Yes, to make your server more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions for your my.cnf/ini [mysqld] section

```
query_prealloc_size=32K  # from default to avoid RAM acquisition all day
query_alloc_block_size=32K  # from default to manage larger blocks
query_cache_limit=16K  # from 1M to minimize qcache_lowmem_prunes
query_cache_min_res_unit=512  # from ? to minimum for more queries_in_cache
```

Hope to see some feedback and similar statistics one day after implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions for your my.cnf-ini [mysqld] section to consider

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=10G  # from 128M to reduce innodb_buffer_pool_reads
innodb_lru_scan_depth=128  # from 1024 per REFMAN when ibp_instances=8
expire_logs_days=5  # from 0 for limited historical error,general,slow logs
slow_query_log=ON  # from OFF to allow awareness of ~ 2000 in 76 days, for improvement of queries
thread_cache_size=100  # from 12 to reduce threads_created 353K
thread_concurrency=30  # from 10 for more concurrency
max_connections=200  # from 400 for max_used_connections 56 x ~ 4
innodb_io_capacity=1000  # from 200 to open the door wider
key_age_threshold=64800  # from 300 second discard to RD again
innodb_change_buffer_max_size=10  # from 25% to reduce set aside for CHGS, etc
max_write_lock_count=16  # from HUGE number to allow RD after nn lcks
join_buffer_size=128k  # from 4096 for join capacity increase
sort_buffer_size=2M  # from 256K to reduce sort_merge_passes ~ 1m
updatable_views_with_limit=NO  # from YES to reduce handler_external_lock cnt
```

handler_rollback had 3,412,265 incidents to deal with.  Need 1 minute of SET GLOBAL innodb_print_all_deadlocks=ON; -  then OFF to avoid filling drive.  Post applicable part of error log for analysis, please.